# What is the cokernel of the map $A:\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z^7$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider the free $\mathbb Z$ - modules $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb Z^7$ and consider the $\mathbb Z$ - module map $A:\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z^7$ given by, $$\left(\begin{array}*&1&1&0&-1&-1&-1&0\\&0&2&1&3&0&-1&-1\end{array}\right)^T$$

**I need help with finding the cokernel of this map.**

So I know that $\operatorname{Coker} A=\mathbb Z^7/\operatorname{Im}A$ and $A$ is injective, so that rank of $\operatorname{Im}A$ is 2. This means that $\operatorname{Coker}A\cong \mathbb Z^5$.

However I want to calculate it explicitly, with generators.

So we  have that $$\operatorname{Im}A=\{(x,x+2y,y,-x+3y,-x,-x-y,-y)\ |\ x,y\in \mathbb Z\}$$ $$\Longrightarrow\operatorname{Im}A=\mathbb Z\cdot u_1\oplus\mathbb Z\cdot u_2$$
Where $u_1=(1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0)$ and $u_2=(0,2,1,3,0,-1,-1)$.

But I am unsure how to proceed from here to find $\dfrac{\mathbb Z^7}{\mathbb Zu_1\oplus\mathbb Zu_2}$

Thank you.

Comment: Beware, $\operatorname{Coker}A\cong \mathbb Z^5$ will generally be false. For instance $n\mapsto 2n$ is an injective map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that the cokernel is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and not $0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama, yes you are right. So what is it here that ensures it is Coker $A\cong\mathbb Z^5$? Or am I wrong in thinking Coker$A\cong\mathbb Z^5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily determine the cokernel if you first find the Smith normal form of the map's matrix, which in your case is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
^T
~.
\end{equation*}
This means that the two columns $u_1$ and $u_2$ of your matrix can be completed, by additional five columns,  to a basis of the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}^7$, so the cokernel is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^5$.

If you do not know the Smith normal form, you may start by looking it up in Wikipedia, and then learn how to obtain [the Smith normal form of a matrix with integer entries](http://www3.nd.edu/~sevens/smithform.pdf).

Comment: If the second column were $0,2$ instead of $0,1$ in the Smith normal form how would that change the answer?

Comment: The cokernel would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^5\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. I did not look very closely at the essay about the Smith normal form of a matrix with integer entries which I cited, but I am sure that it does not only tell how to produce the Smith form, but also suggests what to do with it once you have it, what kind of questions you can answer, what kind of problems you can solve, and how. If you won't find it in this essay, just google Smith normal form, there are a lot of class notes and such about it on the web.

Comment: Thank you. I have found some sources as well as checked in Dummit and Foote. Things are slowly becoming clearer to me.